# Is it free to register a company on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, companies-page

Can't find information about pricing for company registration here. Could someone help, please? 
Company needs to provide support for it's customers (create tags, answer questions)

Comment: Not sure what is unclear or off topic about this question.

Comment: @Braiam I voted to close it originally as unclear because the question is all over the place.  The accepted answer talks about teams and talent now, but when I originally voted to close, it only mentioned talent (with a comment to add the teams link back).  The question was recently edited to mention creating tags and supporting customers (which has nothing to do with either teams or talent) and invalidates the accepted answer.  The teams and "company pages" tags were added after that, but still don't clarify anything.  and the recent edit contradicts the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The price is $10/month according to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/teams

Edit:

According to my old boss it costs $250 a year to post 1 job on stack overflow, but you are better off just hitting the contact us button here: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Comment: Your first link actually was better. Because that fits more for company. Talent website is more for hiring. Team/Enterprice is more for support, creating tags. Thank you.

Comment: Well i will put it back then

Comment: @IrinaKovalchuk If you want to support your product here instead of using SO for communications between your developers, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support.

Comment: @FeiXiang will check. Thank you.